# Jquery eliminar una clase no especificada de un elemento o eliminar todas las clases a excepción de algunas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tengo un elemento HTML **select#options** que al seleccionar una de las opciones va agregar clases dinamicamente al elemento **div#container**, pero necesito eliminar la clase que se agrego anteriormente a este elemento y luego agregar la nueva clase se la opción seleccionada.

Si se dan cuenta, siempre se agregan las clases pero, pero siguen estando las mismas que se agregaron.

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('change', 'select#options', function(){
    
    var option_selected = $(this).val();
    $('#container').addClass(option_selected);
    $('#container').html(option_selected);
    console.log($('#container').attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options" id="options">
 <option value="" selected>Select</option>
 <option value="style1">Style 1</option>
 <option value="style2">Style 2</option>
 <option value="style3">Style 3</option>
 <option value="style4">Style 4</option>
 <option value="style5">Style 5</option>
</select> 

<div id="container" class="container default"></div>
```

*Agradezco mucho su ayuda.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la función `removeClassPrefix` de esta [respuesta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10835425/2097224) se podría quedar de esta manera:

```js
$.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
    this.each(function(i, el) {
        var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
            return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
        });
        el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
    });
    return this;
};

$(document).on('change', 'select#options', function(){

    var option_selected = $(this).val();
    
    $('#container').removeClassPrefix('style').addClass(option_selected);   
    
    $('#container').html(option_selected);
    console.log($('#container').attr('class'));    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options" id="options">
 <option value="" selected>Select</option>
 <option value="style1">Style 1</option>
 <option value="style2">Style 2</option>
 <option value="style3">Style 3</option>
 <option value="style4">Style 4</option>
 <option value="style5">Style 5</option>
</select> 

<div id="container" class="container default"></div>
```

La función elimina todas las clase empezando por el string `style` que pueda haber y agrega luego el `style` deseado.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias cambiar la linea

```
$('#container').addClass(option_selected);
```

por

```
$('#container').removeClass("style1 style2 style3 style4 style5" ).addClass(option_selected);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias nico

Answer (score 0):

Hola de hecho en cada llamada puedes eliminar "Todas las clases".

```
$('#container').removeClass();  // sin parametros quita todas las clases
```

otra opción puede ser:

```
$('#container').attr('class', '');  // quita todas las clases
```

Después haces tu `.addClass()` como siempre.